# I can`t get access token using python sdk

Tags: python, django, docusignapi, docusign-sdk

I want to get access token with python. this is my code:

```
def get_access_token(request):
    with open("path/to/private.key", "r") as f:
        RAS_PRIVATE_KEY = f.read()
    RAS_PRIVATE_KEY = RAS_PRIVATE_KEY.encode("ascii").decode("utf-8")
    api_client = ApiClient()
    host_name = "account-d.docusign.com"
    api_client.set_oauth_host_name(oauth_host_name=host_name)
    api_client.host = "https://account-d.docusign.com"
    token = api_client.request_jwt_user_token(
        client_id=settings.CLIENT_ID,
        user_id=settings.IMPERSONATED_USER_ID,
        oauth_host_name=host_name,
        private_key_bytes=RAS_PRIVATE_KEY,
        expires_in=3600,
        scopes=['signature', 'impersonation']
    )
    access_token = token.access_token
    return access_token
```

But this error will occurre:

```
docusign_esign.client.api_exception.ApiException: (444)
Reason: 
Trace-Token: 2f2837d6-883f-4511-821f-09a8fee568ab
Timestamp: Tue, 11 Apr 2023 23:34:09 GMT
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Content-Type': 'text/html', 'X-DocuSign-TraceToken': '2f2837d6-883f-4511-821f-09a8fee568ab', 'X-DocuSign-Node': 'DA2DFE4', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload', 'Referrer-Policy': 'no-referrer,strict-origin-when-cross-origin', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'Date': 'Tue, 11 Apr 2023 23:34:09 GMT', 'Content-Length': '54', 'Connection': 'close', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding'})
HTTP response body: b'The custom error module does not recognize this error.'
```

Then I set `oauth_host_name="https://demo.docusign.net/restapi"` and another error will occurre:

```
raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='https', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: //demo.docusign.net/restapi/oauth/token (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7ff19117d450>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution'))
```

I don't know where the problem is.How I can solve it?

Answer (score 0):

So based on the error it looks like it is routing the request to demo.docusign.net/... which is incorrect. It should be account-d.docusign.net.

In the [Python Code examples](https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-python/blob/fb5ced44309a2e2e6d364dec7221d81f55e9785e/app/jwt_helpers/jwt_helper.py#L4), the API Client object is initialised and set to the base path using api_client.set_base_path(oauth_base_path);

You may want to try that instead of api_client.host

Comment: The code changed to:
`api_client = ApiClient()`
`api_client.set_base_path("account-d.docusign.net")`
`response = api_client.request_jwt_user_token(`
        `client_id=settings.CLIENT_ID,`
        `user_id=settings.IMPERSONATED_USER_ID,`
        `oauth_host_name="account-d.docusign.net",`
        `private_key_bytes=RAS_PRIVATE_KEY,`
        `expires_in=4000,`
        `scopes=['signature', 'impersonation']`
    `)`

but the same error will occure:
`raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))`